# What does "XXX" Weighted Range influence?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In further understanding advanced map creation i want to know more about the specific parameters that can be set. For each terrain type you have a weighted range with numbers behind it. Also does the mesh size have influence on these setting directly?

Do the numbers behind it mean how dominant the type is? So if i put Temperature Weighted Range (0-20) on "NONE" it means there will be no low temperature tiles? This seems to be not working.

For volcanism does this mean how high a volcano in an area will grow? In another question i was told that if you put (0-20) and (80-100) on "1" and the rest on "NONE" there will be no volcanism at all (0-20), i guess neither a magma shaft or there WILL be a volcano (80-100).

If i put further up a minimal value of 20 then i guess it is of no use to put the weighted range (0-20) of the same type to anything other then none.

The FAQ explains so little about all these little settings so i hope Arqade can shed some light on the advanced parameters, expect some more questions about the advanced world generator of Dwarf fortress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weighted range values do not fully restrict the distribution to those values, but make it so that *on average*, the values will be spread close to as specified. Quick aside in reference to your other question, only surface volcanism is affected. Magma shafts can still exist in 0 volcanism.

I don't believe it is possible to generate a map with no low temperature areas, for the sake of full world simulation. It should, however, be lowering the amount of world which is cold.

The way weighed ranges and mesh sizes are thought to work is that the mesh size creates a grid of lines on the map. At each intersection of the lines, a value for a given property is randomly chosen, with weighting accounted for. The tiles between the intersections are then smoothed between adjacent values. Adjusting the mesh size will change the size of homogenous areas.

Weighted range has no effect on height of volcano. To be honest, I'm not sure what effects that. I suspect it just takes advantage of existing terrain. Volcanos can only exist in tiles with 100 volcanism.